# Dynamic Tailwind width class not working consistently in react component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, class, tailwind-css

I've read over a few posts that address an issue similar to this. And Ive tried their solutions but nothing seems to work consistently work for me.
I am building a progress bar and the issue Im having is the value I am passing for width doesnt seem to be working, it works for w-0, w-1/4 but after that when i pass in w-2/4 or w-3/4 it starts to behave as if Ive set width full. Ive done all the testing to see if im passing in the correct value, Ive hardcoded the class to make sure the value would behave as expected and they do. I've even added in these classes to my tailwind.config.js files safelist:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  safelist: ['w-0', 'w-1/4', 'w-2/4', 'w-3/4', 'w-full'],
...
}
```

But for some reason i do not know tailwind is ignoring my width value. this is my component:

```
return (
    <div className={`my-4 h-2.5 w-full rounded-full ${backgroundColor}`}>
      <div className={`${fraction} transition-width h-2.5 rounded-full duration-500 ${progressColor} `}></div>
    </div>
  );
```

Fraction will always equal 'w-0', 'w-1/4', 'w-2/4', 'w-3/4', or 'w-full'.
Is there something im missing about tailwind classes that could be causing this issue?
Also, when I initially implemented this it was working perfectly fine I created a recording of it so I have proof Im not crazy. But then it just stops working. Why could this be?

UPDATE: I removed the transition-width and duration-500 from the classes an now it is working again. But it is unclear why that would cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.
I needed to add `transition-width` to my `tailwind.config.js` file like so

```
module.exports = {
...
transitionProperty: {
         'width': 'width',
        }
}
```

Without this customization tailwind will not recognize `transition-width`.